# Repeat String Infinitely - Return Count of Specific Character Within N Length of Infinite String - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

Trying to solve this [HackerRank challenge](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/repeated-string/problem?h_l=interview&playlist_slugs%5B%5D=interview-preparation-kit&playlist_slugs%5B%5D=warmup):

> Lilah has a string, **s**, of lowercase English letters that she repeated infinitely many times.
>
> Given an integer, **n**, find and print the number of letter a's in the first  letters of Lilah's infinite string.
>
> For example, if the string **s = abcac** and **n = 10**, the substring we consider is **abcacabcac**, the first **10** characters of her infinite string. There are **4** occurrences of "a" in the substring.

I wrote:

```js
function repeatedString(s, n) {

    s = s.repeat(n);
    s = s.slice(0, n);
    
    let array = Array.from(s);
    let count = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        let char = array[i];
        if (char.match(/[a]/gi)) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
console.log(repeatedString("abcac", 10));
```

But HackerRank does not like `s = s.repeat(n);`, apparently:

[image]

I'm not sure how else to generate a string of an appropriate length to slice from. `s = s.repeat(Infinity)` does not work, and `s` is **not** already repeated an infinite number of times when it's passed in as a parameter.

I.e. console.logging(s), initially, logs

> abcac

In this case.

I also tried:

```js
function repeatedString(s, n) {

  let j = n;
  let newString = "";
  while (n > 0) {
      newString += s;
      n--;
  }
  
  newString = newString.slice(0, j);
  let count = 0;
  let array = Array.from(newString);
 
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
      let char = array[i];
      if (char.match(/[a]/gi)) {
          count++;
      }
  }
  return count;
}
console.log(repeatedString("abcac", 10));
```

But this caused a timeout error.

Any other ideas for how to create a string of valid length to slice from?

**EDIT**:

**Constraints:**

> 1 <= |s| <= 100
>
> 1 <= n <= 10^12
>
> For **25%** of the test cases, **n <= 10^6**

Comment: If s contains "a" 3 times, and s gets repeated four times to be of length n, then the answer is 3 * 4. For n= infinity, that'll be 3 * Infinity, which will result in Infinity... For sure you have to consider were s.length % n !== 0, but thats not too complicated.

Comment: For the second snippet, I'm not getting a timeout error. Is that the case with anybody else?

Comment: @Tuneer causes a timeout error _on HackerRank_, and all of the answers below do as well.

Comment: @JonasWilms added constraints for n in the edit - `1 <= n <= 10^12`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

actually repeating the string *n* times is a tremendous waste of memory and runtime.

just compute how often the entire string would be repeated times how many `a`s the string has plus the number of `a`s in the part of `s.slice(0, n%s.length)`

And your runtime goes down to `s.length` instead of `n`

```js
function repeatedString(s, n) {
  var r = n % s.length,
    m = (n - r) / s.length,
    count = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i < s.length; ++i) {
    if (s[i] === "a") {
      count += m + (i < r);
    }
  }
  return count;
}

console.log(repeatedString("abcac", 1234567890));
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
function repeatedString(s, n) {
  var r = n % s.length,
    m = (n - r) / s.length,
    count = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i < s.length; ++i) {
    if (s[i] === "a") {
      count += m + (i < r);
    }
  }
  return count;
}

console.log(repeatedString("abcac", 1234567890));
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

I tested this and knows it works. Essentially, I'm not creating a new string, I just find out how many times I have to multiply the original string in order to be able to truncate it. Then I multiply that number by how many a's there were in the original string.

```js
function repeatedString(s, n) {

    var charLength = s.length;
    var repeat = Math.floor(n/charLength);
    var remainder = n%(charLength);
    var strCut = s.slice(0, remainder);
    
    let count = 0;
    let arrayX = Array.from(s);
    for (let i = 0; i < arrayX.length; i++) {
        let char = arrayX[i];
        if (char.match(/[a]/gi)) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    
    count = count * repeat;
    
    let arrayY = Array.from(strCut);
    for (let i = 0; i < arrayY.length; i++) {
        let char = arrayY[i];
        if (char.match(/[a]/gi)) {
            count++;
        }
    }

    return count;
}

console.log(repeatedString("abcac", 10));
```

Comment: Needs to also work for other strings i.e. `"aba"` though I think we're on the right track - no timeout error here.

Comment: @HappyHands31 changed it to work for other strings.

Comment: Yeah I just tried those changes as well and unfortunately, timeout error: https://i.imgur.com/1XZeXUg.png

Comment: @HappyHands31 try this. if there's any other problems, let me know.

Answer (score 1):

I tried a small solution with `.repeat` but as Thomas said, it's expensive and was taking ages to run tests.

```js
function repeatedString(s, n) {
    const allAs = s.match(/a/g);
    if (!allAs) {
        return 0;
    }
    if (s === 'a') {
        return n;
    }
    const reps = s.repeat(Math.ceil(n/s.length)).slice(0, n).match(/a/g)
    if (!reps) return 0;
    return reps.length;
};

console.log(repeatedString('abc', 10));
console.log(repeatedString('abcde', 10));
```

But I followed Thomas idea and came up with a simpler solution

```js
function repeatedString(s, n) {
    const allAs = s.match(/a/g);
    if (!allAs) {
        return 0;
    }
    if (s === 'a') {
        return n;
    }
    const rem = n % s.length;
    const reps = (n-rem)/s.length;
    let count = reps * allAs.length;
    if (rem) {
        const rest = s.slice(0, rem).match(/a/g);
        if (rest) count = count + rest.length
    }
    return count;
}

console.log(repeatedString('a', 100000));
console.log(repeatedString('abcde', 10000000000));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `while` loop to repeat original string until length is matched and then `match` to count the numbers of `a`.

```js
function repeatedString(s, n) {
  let i = 0, l = s.length;
  while (s.length < n) s += s[i++ % l]
  return s.match(/a/g).length;
}
console.log(repeatedString("abcac", 10));
```

Comment: The question is about `n = Infinity`.

Comment: Tried it, its failing many tests and taking ages to run them. Also super-difficult to read

Answer (score 0):

I did this code and it worked well.

```
function repeatedString(s, n) {
    let modulus = n % s.length;
    let repetition = (n - modulus) / s.length;
    let remainCounts = s.slice(0, modulus).split("").filter((item) => item == "a").length
    
    return (s.split("").filter((item) => item == "a").length * repetition) + remainCounts
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T3SYL.png)

Answer (score 0):

Creating an infinite string and calculating is very costly. Instead of that calculating how many times 'a' repeats in the input string and multiple max occurrences can happens seems a good way of doing it.

1. Find the reminder after the original string is repeated as whole in the limit.
2. Find the maximum time input string can fit in the allowed length as whole.
3. count the a's occurrence and multiply by maxCompleteOccur + a' s occurrence in the reminder string.

Used PHP [substr_count()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr-count.php) to count the number of substring occurrences

```html
function repeatedString($s, $n) {
    
    // Find the reminder after the original string is repeated as whole
    $reminder = $n % (strlen($s)); 


    // Find the maximum time input string can fit in the allowed length
    $maxCompleteOccur = floor($n / strlen($s));



    // count the a's occurance and multiply by maxCompleteOccur + a's occurance in reminder string. 
    return floor(substr_count($s, 'a') * $maxCompleteOccur) + substr_count($s, 'a', 0, $reminder);

}
```